# $ax\equiv b\pmod c$ is equivalent to $x\equiv rb\pmod c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> How are these $2$ equations equivalent ?

If $\gcd(a,c)=1$, and $r,s\in\mathbb Z:ra+sc=1$

$ax\equiv b\pmod c\tag1$ and

$x\equiv rb\pmod c\tag2$

Is there a mistake in the formula ? ($s$ doesn't appear)

Comment: Yes, $s$ is irrelevant - think of the formula as $ra\equiv 1\pmod c$, and that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all: $a^{-1}\equiv r\mod c$ since $1=ar+sc\equiv ar \mod c$.